# How to create JavaScript regex which test if a line start with '//'

Tags: javascript

How to create JavaScript regex which tests if a line starting with '//'

I try using

```
var isCommentReget = /^\/\//
```

to test for line starts with //

And how can I test it so that it can return turn if a line starts with tab, space, and then "//'?

But isCommentReget always returns true.  Please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Are you testing it against multiline text or single line text?

Comment: How are you testing it that it always "returns true"?

Comment: can you share your example, illustrating the test with which it returns true.

`/^[\t\s](\/){2}.*/` regex should help you to check if a line start with tab, space and then "//'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited with Niet's regex pattern; Quick example

```js
const test = [
    "blah blah blah blah",
    "  // blah blah blah blah",
    "//blah blah blah blah",
    "blahblahblahblah"
  ];
  
for (i = 0, x = test.length; i < x; i++) {
  console.log((/^\s*\/\//m.test(test[i]) ? 'YES match found' : 'No match') + ` at index ${i}`);
}
```

Comment: Whoever's the quick trigger to downvote, mind explaining why so maybe others can learn something? Anonymous down-voting generally doesn't help anyone...

Comment: Certainly. This does not answer the question. It is testing an array of strings, not a full string with "lines starting with `//`". It does not help the OP debug their attempt, which prevents them from learning. That's why we're asking questions in the comments of the question, trying to figure out what the problem is, rather than dropping in a tangentially-related "solution".

Comment: Your edit actually makes it worse, as it will only work for *exactly* two spaces or tabs, and it still does not address the "line starting with" part.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm unclear then how I'm misinterpreting "And how can I test it so that it can return turn if a line start with tab, space and then "//'?" or how it makes anything worse :D

Comment: Well, by making it "work" for "tab, space and then '//'" you've made it no longer work for lines that just start with `//`, defeating the word "and" in "and how can I..."

Comment: So it just needs an OR?

Comment: And now you're using two separate regexes when you only need one. `/^\s*\/\//m`

Comment: This is why I downvoted. Your answer does not have enough thought put into it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol then why not answer it? ...and yea I'm no regex guru :D

Comment: Because OP hasn't provided the information we've requested in order to be able to effectively help them. Answering now is premature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer for checking line start with '//'

```js
var str1 = "//The best things in life are free";
var str2 = "The //best things in life are free";

var regex = new RegExp("^(\/\/)");

console.log("str1: ", regex.test(str1));
console.log("str2: ", regex.test(str2));
```

Comment: This checks if *the whole string* starts with `//`, not if a *line* starts with `//`.

Comment: Yea you might want to read Niet's comments on the line below, seems we're all quick on the trigger in one form or another lol.